# Python: can not import lxml.etree.xmlfile

Tags: python, lxml

Trying to use lxml for xml file generation.

in API documentation it is stated that class xmlfile exists:
http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.xmlfile-class.html

I use import:

```
from lxml import etree
```

but when executing getting an error

```
global name 'xmlfile' is not defined" on line:
with xmlfile(os.path.join(self.path, "filename.xml"), encoding='windows-1251') as xf:
```

Comment: Where do you import `xmlfile`?

Comment: Should perhaps be `with etree.xmlfile(...`? (I.e., the only name that gets directly assigned by the import is `etree` -- you then need to reference its "members" using dot notation.)

Comment: I belie when import etree

Comment: Andrew i tried that it returned AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xmlfile'

Answer (score 2):

Python import semantics are different than you seem to expect.

```
from <package> import <name>
```

doesn't make all names *in* `<name>` available.

You need to go through `<name>`, so in your case `etree.xmlfile`.

Comment: tried that it returned AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xmlfile'

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `xmlfile` to `etree.xmlfile`.

```
 from lxml import etree    ### don't change this

 with etree.xmlfile(os.path.join(self.path, "filename.xml"), encoding='windows-1251') as xf:
```

Comment: tried that it returned AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xmlfile'

Comment: you need to do `from lxml import etree` and then `etree.xmlfile()` works fine on my box.

Comment: could you please state version of imported lxml?

Comment: I'm on Python 2.7.6 using lxml 3.4.4

Comment: when I'm doing it in new file it works, but when in mine it returns an error. I tried to import with different name: import lxml.etree as crabtree but it didn't helped.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xmlfile'

Comment: show the full source of your code or we can't help you

Comment: print 'lxml.etree.__path__' to see where the module is located.